# dose openshift Website Nameservers is static or will be change

Tags: static, openshift, nameservers

i am new for openshift apps, so i make an app in openshift website and i need to point a domain to its web address .

so my domain provider only allowed to set domain based on Website Nameservers . so i want to know is my Website Nameservers i openshift is static, or may be changing in future.

For example my site address is

> **app-mysite.rhcloud.com**

and it's Nameserver is :

> **ns1.p23.dynect.net**    with IP **208.78.70.23**

.so if i set my domain NS Recorde to **ns1.p23.dynect.net** it will work .and Nameserver of **app-mysite.rhcloud.com** will be change in future or no. (Because in openshift site they have said IP address of app-mysite.rhcloud.com maybe change do to server maintenance or ...)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to configure custom domain names with your OpenShift applications is through the use of CNAME certs, see this post for more information https://www.openshift.com/blogs/domain-names-and-ssl-in-the-openshift-web-console. That being said providing the name of your domain provider might be helpful.

Your application IP will inevitably change since your application will unlikely stay on that node. Take a look at the article I mentioned earlier and if you follow those steps your custom domain should persist regardless of your application IP.